# Way to avoid treating part of LINQ expression binding as part of an entity query generation

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, expression

We have one Guid assignment in the following code:

```
Guid guid= new Guid("e187714f-9ec8-46c3-8eb0-844fd3bc40c9");
var test= (from s in db.SolidResources.AsNoTracking()
                    select new Db.SolidResourceDb()
                    {
                        Serial = s.Serial,
                        Revision = s.Revision,
                        InternalId = guid
                   }
```

This generates following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    cast('e187714f-9ec8-46c3-8eb0-844fd3bc40c9' as uniqueidentifier) AS [C2], 
    [Extent1].[Serial] AS [Serial], 
    [Extent1].[Revision] AS [Revision], 
    FROM   [resource].[SolidResource] AS [Extent1]
```

We change that guid for each query call. This causes Entity Framework's compiled query cache not work because each time it is a new query(or at least it thinks so). This makes big performance hit. Is there a way to assign that Guid but remove it from SQL query generated so compiled query cache feature of Entity Framework would work?

To me it is a bug in Entity Framework because it should cache SQL queries which are identical even if LINQ expression has some unrelated to SQL expressions.

Comment: Can you escape the EF-domain and do the projection based on the return value? Something like `.AsEnumerable()`?

Comment: what is this `Db.SolidResourceDb` ?

Comment: Why do you have `s.InternalId = guid` and not just `InternalId = guid`?

Comment: "s." was a typo, i fixed it

Comment: Andreas, we have to use real IQuerable lists because we deal with huge joins on large tables. Putting all this in memory is not an option. We also use sorting and paging on those joins so it has to be SQL.

Comment: Every record gets the same GUID correct?  Why not just return the IQueryable and the guid from the method and compose the object after all of your joins/filters are applied

Comment: Matthew, yes, that guid is constant for all records returned, we use it for tracking purposes of result sets and many other things that go out of scope of this topic. The solution of doing a for loop after all the calls is not feasable for us. The code you see is simplification.

Comment: What version of Entity Framework do you use?

Comment: With similar query I'm getting Sql parameter, not constant value (EF6.1.3). Same should be for yours except if there is something you haven't shown.

Comment: EF version is 6.0

Comment: Then may be it's a good time to switch to EF6.1.3. This might be a bug that has been fixed.